# Need help for disable particular hover jQuery animation in smaller device

Tags: jquery, html, animation, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

This is my jQuery code

```
$('.sol-card-container').hover(function () {
    $(".card-content", this).stop().animate({top: '160px'}, {queue: false,duration: 100});
    $(".cta-txt-link", this).stop().animate({bottom: '-65px'}, {queue: false,duration: 600});
}, function () {
    $(".card-content", this).stop().animate({top: '0px'}, {queue: false,duration: 100});
    $(".cta-txt-link", this).stop().animate({bottom: '0px'}, {queue: false,duration: 600});

});
```

HTML part i have using the Bootstrap 3 version.
What my issues is, these jQuery code working fine in Desktop layout, but i need to disable the animation in <767px breakpoint.

Can anyone suggest me how to disable

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap everything inside a `resize` event like :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $w = $(window);
    var breakpoint = 768;

    $w.on('resize', function(){
        if ($w.width() < breakpoint)
            return false;

        $('.sol-card-container').hover(function () {
            $(".card-content", this).stop().animate({top: '160px'}, {queue: false,duration: 100});
            $(".cta-txt-link", this).stop().animate({bottom: '-65px'}, {queue: false,duration: 600});
        }, function () {
            $(".card-content", this).stop().animate({top: '0px'}, {queue: false,duration: 100});
            $(".cta-txt-link", this).stop().animate({bottom: '0px'}, {queue: false,duration: 600});

        });

    }).trigger('resize');

});
```

And to call the code when the page is loaded, not only when resized we should tirgger resize event( note `trigger('resize')` ).

If you plan to extend your resize function with much more complex stuff i will go for adding a [debounced resize](http://www.paulirish.com/2009/throttled-smartresize-jquery-event-handler/) for a better performance

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your script in a `if` statement that will check if `$(window).width()` is greater than `767px` and run the script if so:

```
jQuery(function($) {

    if($(window).width() > 767) {

        $('.sol-card-container').hover(/* ... */);

    }

});
```

And if you want to listen on browser resizing, wrap the whole script in:

```
jQuery(function($) {

    $(window).on('resize', function() {

        if($(this).width() > 767) {
            $('.sol-card-container').hover(/* ... */);
        }

    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks for quick update, but here i faced some issue.
This one its happend once resized the window.  But i need the animation till Bootstrap col-sm-*, without